# In Quorum running raft consensus, what happens if one node attempts to modify the state via modofying the physical file?

Tags: quorum

In quorum running raft consensus, what happens if one node attempts to modify the state via modifying the physical file? Assuming this is even possible in the first place.

Will the update be sync across the network? Or will the updated node have its change overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the node mucks with its local DB, this node will fall out of sync with the blockchain and will not advance its chain anymore. This is unmodified from original Ethereum and is part of block validation process.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some way to restore and backup the state/localdb? Is it leveldb that we are using?

Comment: As mentioned in another reply, back up the --datadir that you write data to and thats sufficient.